# Ignore quotes in pandas csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV like this:

```
A  B  C  D                     E   F  G
-- -- -- --------------------- --- -- --
G1 M1 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N1
G1 M1 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N2
G1 M1 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N3
G2 M2 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N1
G2 M2 C1 "1/1/2015 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N2
G2 M2 C1 "1/1/2015 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N3
```

I need to read this into a pandas df and ignore the quotes in column D so that I can parse it into a date time column. I've tried to do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
        infile,
        sep=r"\s*(?![0-9][0-9]:)",
        skiprows=[1],
        header=0,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
    )
```

But the resulting df still has quotes in it:

```
>>> df
    A   B   C                      D    E   F   G
0  G1  M1  C1  "2015-01-01 00:00:00"  SR1  E1  N1
1  G1  M1  C1  "2015-01-01 00:00:00"  SR1  E1  N2
2  G1  M1  C1  "2015-01-01 00:00:00"  SR1  E1  N3
3  G2  M2  C1  "2015-01-01 00:00:00"  SR1  E1  N1
4  G2  M2  C1    "1/1/2015 00:00:00"  SR1  E1  N2
5  G2  M2  C1    "1/1/2015 00:00:00"  SR1  E1  N3
```

If I try to parse column D as a datetime column directly, pandas breaks:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.D)
...
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

How can I get column D formatted in such a way that pandas can parse it as a date column?

Pandas version: 0.19.2

Comment: Try this: `pd.read_csv(infile, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=[1])`

Comment: This doesn't remove quotes, and it also splits column D into 2 columns.

Comment: What is your Pandas version?

Comment: Ah, it looks like I needed to remove the other arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [44]: df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\1.csv', delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=[1], 
                          parse_dates=['D'])

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
    A   B   C          D    E   F   G
0  G1  M1  C1 2015-01-01  SR1  E1  N1
1  G1  M1  C1 2015-01-01  SR1  E1  N2
2  G1  M1  C1 2015-01-01  SR1  E1  N3
3  G2  M2  C1 2015-01-01  SR1  E1  N1
4  G2  M2  C1 2015-01-01  SR1  E1  N2
5  G2  M2  C1 2015-01-01  SR1  E1  N3

In [46]: df.dtypes
Out[46]:
A            object
B            object
C            object
D    datetime64[ns]
E            object
F            object
G            object
dtype: object
```

where `D:\download\1.csv`:

```
A  B  C  D                     E   F  G
-- -- -- --------------------- --- -- --
G1 M1 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N1
G1 M1 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N2
G1 M1 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N3
G2 M2 C1 "2015-01-01 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N1
G2 M2 C1 "1/1/2015 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N2
G2 M2 C1 "1/1/2015 00:00:00" SR1 E1 N3
```